# External drive with Time Machine not visible

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility, partition

mac os monterey 12.5.1

My external drive 2to is split into two partition of 1to

- One called **backup001**: it is formated mac os, and it uses for timemachine for a long time. it works ok.
- Another partition is called **backup002thunder**: it is used to be for formated exfat, but recently formated mac os to be used for timemachine as well.

The **backup002thunder** is mount/visible on my mac but NOT VISIBLE in timemachine to be selected as a backup destination. (but this partition is visible in option if i want to exclude the disk from timemachine)

WHY CAN T I SELECT THE DISK AS ANOTHER TIMEMACHINE BACKUP? (I have another external disk called **thunder** and that one is visible (formated APFS)

what I want:

- **backup001** 1to: used the partition backup001 for internal SSD backup. it used to be like that. I want to keep it that way
- **backup002thunder** 1to: I want to backup an external SSD (called here **thunder**) on that partition.

how can I do that?

thanks[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If backup001 is already used by TM, why do you want to add it again?

Comment: Having said that: If you select backup002 as a backup destination, your internal disk will get backed up to it. Is this what you want?

Comment: If you persuade Backup 2 then what you'll have is two sets of almost identical backups *of all your drives* on two partitions *on the same physical drive*. I don't see this as being any better or safer than just using the entire drive. You can't set both backups to have different sources anyway. BTW, you didn't tell us what macOS you're on. That may make all the difference. It looks like you're on Big Sur or newer, which would mean Time Machine wants an APFS-formatted drive to backup to.

Comment: I am using mac os monterey 12.5.1

Comment: First, I don t get why TM can t see my drive. secondly, I wish to backup internal drive on one partition (backup01) and my external drive on partition 2 (backup02) i don t know if it is possible :)

Comment: Time Machine must be on an APFS-formatted disk for Monterey, not HFS+. You cannot make one disk back up to one Time Machine & another disk to another TM. Time Machine backs up everything in your allowed list to both drives. What you are attempting is not going to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid what you want is not achievable.

Firstly, the reason the Backup002 drive cannot be seen by Time Machine is that it must be formatted APFS to be used. HFS+ drives could be used on older macOS but not since big Sur.
Strictly speaking, t will allow to to *continue* to use an HFS+ disk if a Time Machine backup is already on it. It will not allow you to start a new one. - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15139/mac

Secondly, you cannot set two different backup strategies for two Time Machine backups. This would mean Time Machine will simply make the same backup to each partition in turn, separated by an hour.

Comment: one of my partition is formated  mac os (backup002thunder is formated the same way) not APFS and it is still visible from time machine. so it doesn t make sense for the second partition still not visible formated the same say. but for the your secondly, i get it. thanks

Comment: It will allow to to *continue* to use an HFS+ disk if a Time Machine backup is already on it. It will not allow you to start a new one. - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15139/mac